# jQuery Pjax: losing access to jquery with frequent clicks of pjax-ified links?

Tags: jquery, browser-history, pushstate, pjax

i'm using the jquery Pjax plugin from Chris Wanstrath, aka, Defunkt, demo'd here: http://pjax.heroku.com.

I've got it working exactly as the demo. However, sometimes that seem to correlate with too frequent clicking of pjax'd links or the browser back/forward button, my layout file loses access to jquery and the pjax() functionality falls apart (i.e., full page loading of selected href happens).

I was wondering if this is just browser javascript engine slowness (happens in both chrome and firefox and on my xampp localhost as well as at pjax.heroku.com) where too frequent click events and ajax calls confuse the browser resulting in it ignoring already loaded javascript (i.e., jquery).

Not sure if this hypothesis makes any sense but don't have any other explanations for what seems haphazard at the moment,

any thoughts would be greatly appreciated,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, i had not realized there was a 'timeout' option whose default is set to less than 1 second, i bumped that up to a couple of seconds and then pjax() doesn't fail anymore,